# "Tехника не новая" или "техника неновая"?

Tags: предлоги, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательными

Как правильно написать "техника не новая" в предложении:

> В хозяйстве не скрывают: техника не_новая

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта допустимы, при этом возможны следующие смысловые оттенки:

(1) **В хозяйстве не скрывают: техника не новая** (не со склада, уже хотя бы однажды использованная).

(2) **В хозяйстве не скрывают: техника неновая** (находилась в эксплуатации некоторое время,  изношенность средняя).

Пояснение

1) Существует ли слово ***неновый***?

Прямого запрета на него нет, но в толковом словаре слово не рассматривается. Собственно говоря, он не несет в себе **особого утвердительного смысла, только отрицание:** не является новым.

В Нацкорпусе частотность употребления вариантов ***неновый*** и ***не новый***: 7: 200.

Синонимы для него тоже трудно подобрать: это может быть как ***почти старый,*** так и просто б/у без указания срока эксплуатации.

В то же время **смысловые оттенки всё-таки различимы**: ***неновый*** - это находящийся в эксплуатации определенное время, а ***не новый*** - это не в заводской упаковке, уже хотя бы однажды использованный.

2) **Пример со слитным написанием:**

Но в этот вечер места были заняты едва на треть, ― фильм **неновый**. [Инна Лиснянская, 1999]

Я много лет пиджак ношу, Давно потертый и **неновый**. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

Примечание. Встречаются варианты: давно потертый и **не новый;** давно потерся и **не нов он**.

3) Применять слитную форму удобно **в утвердительных конструкциях (в роли определения)**, например:

Вспоминая узкий в плечах **неновый** костюмчик мента, Люська с умилением думала... [Ольга Некрасова.  (2000)]

Тумаш развязал свой **неновый**, побитый мелкими дырками вещевой мешок, из-под брикетов тола достал два обкрошенных сухаря. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

Comment: Sharon, Как вы получили частотность 7: 200? Я нахожу 52:1692, то есть примерно та же пропорция, но числа большие. Есть несколько путей поиска?

Comment: Поиск по книгам наводит на мысль, что устойчиво-слитное написание слова (несмотря на формально законные признаки для этого) имеет место в терминах "неновый заём/кредит". В остальных случаях "утвердительного" значения этого сочетания, как правило, избегают, несмотря на то, что в некоторых словарях синонимов данное слово упоминается.

Comment: @М_Г Я набрала слова "не новый" и "неновый", для них и указала частотность.

Comment: Sharon, Понял, но такой поиск неполный, не включает вариации по родам, числам, падежам.

Comment: @Alex_ander Знаете, мне тоже сначала показалось, что слитное написание выглядит непривычно. Но потом я посмотрела примеры в Нацкорпусе, и моё мнение изменилось. Если  прочитать их внимательно, то начинаешь ощущать разные смысловые оттенки слов, о которых я уже написала в ответе. Я даже ответ несколько раз исправляла. Вот, например, "фильм неновый".  Он именно неновый, то  есть несколько лет назад вышел на экраны, многие его смотрели. Но и к категории старых фильмов его тоже не отнесешь.

Comment: @М_Г Просто это скорее качественная оценка, здесь не требуется абсолютная точность. Ведь, по Вашим словам, общая пропорция сохранена.

Comment: У меня такое написание вызывает интуитивное неприятие - то ли от похожести на "неоновый", то ли от неестественности применять к этому слову правило "утверждения отрицания" (легче обосновать "отрицание новизны", о котором собеседник мог бы подумать). Видимо, "новое" составляет столь малую часть всего сущего, что странно через его отрицание давать (утвердительное) определение качеству, присущему всему прочему.

Comment: У Вас все ответы немного философские (поэтому Вас всегда интересно читать), но все-таки градация признака, как мне кажется,  здесь есть: новый - не новый - неновый - старый. А у Окуджавы в его стихотворении "Старый пиджак" как вы этот пиджак назовете? Неужели "давно потертый и не новый"?  Ведь здесь между определениями однородные отношения и союз И.

Comment: Как поэтическую вольность или даже прозаический окказионализм, готов терпеть. Но для меня место этого слова в языке примерно такое же, как напр. у слова "некосмонавты".

Comment: Интересное  Вас мнение, но хотелось бы еще кого-нибудь послушать.